# I remember reading a SF book (first in a trilogy) a few years ago, need help finding

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, hard-sci-fi, mars

Here's what I remember:

- The first book is freely available on the author's website.
- Second book is published, but is available through purchase only.
- All the books are supposed to be made open source in 2039 or around then. This is also the year the first book is set in.
- The book is set on Mars.
- There is an AI in the story that is composed of different agents like "Dream", "Logic", "Face", etc. They all have distinct personalities and goals and I think the story is told from the perspective of "Face".
- There is a lesbian couple including a lieutenant and someone else.
- There is a child character who speaks in an advanced version of English where she abbreviates most words.

Answer (score 10):

Is it perhaps ***The Crystal Society*, by Max Harms**?

It is the first book in a completed trilogy, it is freely available for download, along with the other volumes, it's set in 2039; it does not seem to take place on Mars, but Mars has been colonised; the A.I. 'Face' seems to be the narrator and has the siblings (or independent A.I.s she can communicate with) called 'Dream', 'Wiki' (and not 'Logic'), 'Vista', 'Heart', and 'Body', among others. There is a nine-year old called Maid Marian who talks in a kind of telegram-style English (see excerpt below).

From the [dedicated website](http://crystal.raelifin.com/)'s plot description:

> "The year is 2039, and the world is much like ours."
> [..]
> "Privately operated ventures carried humans to the moon and beyond, but space stations have become nothing but government trophies and hiding places for extremists."
> [..]
> "Face is an artificial intelligence created to understand and gain the adoration of all humans."

An excerpt from the book (that is available through that same link, which I'm not going to link directly :):

> [The narrator speaking] "The Dreamer, my brother, was also Dream; he was The Poet and The Muse; he was Invention and Metaphor and a million other things."
> [..]
> ['Maid Marian' speaking] ""Damn! You’re no fun! Didn’t think you’d act just lika grownup. If must know came with Mrs. Dolan.” Marian drew out the words in deliberate contrast with her normally frantic speech, making a melodramatic face to further emphasize the sentiment. “’Course gave her pretty big dose of sevoflurane, so won’t even be awake for when docking at Olympus. Have ever been to Olympus? Dad owns it. Owns the whole thing. Been up there three times before today, but one time was an itty bitty baby so doesn’t really count. You’re a robot. You ever an itty bitty baby?""

[Here](https://app.thestorygraph.com/books/324704e9-5456-47aa-a3cf-c49a4732f799) is a Storygraph link.